# Integrated ant - taskdef classloader issue

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, taskdef

On Weblogic 10.3 my enterprise application includes a webservice that runs ant scripts inside. My problem is that I cannot get my custom tasks running due to `java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptions`.

(All this works well on Tomcat 5.5)

My task implementation can be found in 4 different locations:

- something.ear/APP-INF/lib/antaddon.jar!/foo/bar/MyTask.class
- something.ear/Webservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/antaddon.jar!/foo/bar/MyTask.class
- something.ear/Webservice.war/WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar/MyTask.class
- server/lib/antaddon.jar!/foo/bar/MyTask.class

I see that the `Weblogic 10.3` integrated `Ant 1.6.5` module might cause problems
as I have an `Ant 1.8.0` bundled, so I added

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.apache.ant.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.zip.*</package-name>

</prefer-application-packages>
```

to my weblogic-application.xml to overcome this. (This solved some `NoSuchMethodErrors`..)
However my Task is still not found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.MyTask.class
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:457)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:183)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:142)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:91)
```

can you help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my prefer-application-packages directive was wrong, ant classes are not in `org.apache.ant.*` but in `org.apache.tools.ant.*`. After repairing this my custom class gets loaded and works well from `APP-INF/lib/antaddon.jar`